# Not able to filter elements using an enum

Tags: java-8, enums, java-stream

```
protected static double averagePrice( List<ComputerComponent> list ) { 
    return  list.stream()
            //  .filter( line-> EnumUtils.isValidEnum(ComputerComponentCategory.class, line.getCategory()) )    

            //  .filter( line-> isInEnum( line.getCategory(), ComputerComponentCategory.class) )    
            //   .filter( line->  inEnum(line.getCategory(),EnumUtils.getEnumMap(ComputerComponentCategory.class ).keySet() ))  
                .filter(    line -> 
                        line.getCategory().contains("CPU")  
                        || line.getCategory().contains("GPU")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Monitor")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Keyboard")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Mouse")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Storage")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Memory")) 
               .mapToDouble(ComputerComponent::getPrice)
               .average() 
               .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException:: new); 
    }
```

I have an enum as

```java
public enum ComputerComponentCategory {

    CPU("CPU"), 
    MONITOR("Monitor"), 
    KEYBOARD("Keyboard"), 
    MOUSE("Mouse"), 
    GPU("GPU"), 
    MEMORY("Memory"),
    STORAGE("Storage"),
    NULL("NOT DEFINED"); 

    private String label;

    ComputerComponentCategory(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }

    public static ComputerComponentCategory getValue(String label) {

        switch(label) {
            case "CPU":
                return CPU;
            case "Monitor":
                return MONITOR;
            case "Keyboard":
                return KEYBOARD;
            case "Mouse":
                return MOUSE;
            case "GPU":
                return GPU;
            case "Memory":
                return MEMORY;
            case "Storage":
                return STORAGE;
            default: 
                return NULL ;
        }

    }
}
```

I pass a list of ComputerComponent class to the averagePrice() function which has two fields of price 
    which is of type double and 
    category which is of type String.

My list has 4 elements with categories as "CPU", "Mouse", 
    "Keyboard" and "Storage" with their respective prices as 34.0, 155.0, 23.0 and 75.0.

When I try to use inEnum(), isInEnum() or EnumUtils.isValidEnum() functions, I get the average price 
    as 34.0 which I think that they just return the price of the first element rather than the average.

```
But when I do filtering using 

                            .filter(    line -> 
                        line.getCategory().contains("CPU")  
                        || line.getCategory().contains("GPU")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Monitor")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Keyboard")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Mouse")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Storage")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Memory"))
```

I get the correct average value of 71.75.

The implementations that I have used for isInEnum() and inEnum() functions are the following:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean isInEnum(String value, Class<E> enumClass) {
      for (E e : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        if(e.name().contains(value)) { return true; }
      }
      return false;
    }


public static boolean inEnum ( String category, Set<String> value ) {   
    for(String s: value ) {
    if ( category.contains(s) ) {
        return true ;  
    }
    }
    return false ;
}
```

How can I use enums correctly with java streams to filter by valid category names and get the correct 
    average value of price?

What mistake I am making when using streams and its functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use your `ComputerCategoryValue.getValue` method and check for null, given the category of `line`:

```
public class EnumTest {

    @Test
    public void testBothMethods() {
        final ComputerComponent c1 = new ComputerComponent(ComputerComponentCategory.CPU.getLabel(), 12.21);
        final ComputerComponent c2 = new ComputerComponent(ComputerComponentCategory.MEMORY.getLabel(), 23.45);
        final List<ComputerComponent> list = Arrays.asList(c1, c2);

        assertEquals(averagePriceWithFilter(list), averagePriceWithInEnum(list), 0.01);
    }

    protected static double averagePriceWithFilter(final List<ComputerComponent> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .filter(line -> line.getCategory().contains("CPU")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("GPU")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Monitor")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Keyboard")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Mouse")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Storage")
                        || line.getCategory().contains("Memory"))
                .mapToDouble(ComputerComponent::getPrice)
                .average()
                .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
    }

    protected static double averagePriceWithInEnum(final List<ComputerComponent> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .filter(line -> ComputerComponentCategory.getValue(line.getCategory()) != null)
                .mapToDouble(ComputerComponent::getPrice)
                .average()
                .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
    }
}
```

EDIT: explaining your mistakes:

1. `EnumUtils.getEnumMap(ComputerComponentCategory.class).keySet())` returns a map of the enum name (not its `label`), so that the check will only work for `CPU` as there name and label are the same.
2. Same for the other method!

You need to use `getLabel()` instead of `name()` or use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `contains`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Do you know why EnumUtils.isValidEnum() doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, same explanation applies. `name` of an enum is basically the string representation of the constant, e.g. "MONITOR". Your category is probably using the label "Monitor", which is obviously different (uppercase matters). You could transform the label `toUpperCase`, but I would stronly suggest just using the handy method that your enum provides as in my answer. Maybe even better: Don't use the category-label in your ComputerComponent, but simply have the category property be typed as ComputerComponentCategory and work with the enums directly.